# Tikz \foreach multiple line segments

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I was wondering (I know there is) a simpler way of creating a table using Tikz.  I am currently make columns every x units by hand.  Is there a way I can do this using foreach command?  As you can see it takes alot of time. Thank you for the help.  This section of code is from a larger code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-12)}]
\draw (0.2,22)--(17.8,22)--(17.8,17.5)--(0.2,17.5)--cycle;
\draw (0.2,22)--(17.8,22)node[midway,sloped,draw,rectangle,fill=red!15]{Example 3};
\path (0.2,21)node[anchor=west]{\small The table above gives values of a function  $f$  at selected values of  $x$ . Which of the following conclusions is supported by};
\path (0.2,20.5)node[anchor=west]{\small the data in the table?};
\draw (3.4,20)--(14.8,20)--(14.8,19)--(3.4,19)--cycle;
\draw (4.666,20)--(4.666,19);
\draw (5.9332,20)--(5.9332,19);
\draw (7.1999,20)--(7.1999,19);
\draw (8.45992,20)--(8.45992,19);
\draw (9.7265,20)--(9.7265,19);
\draw (10.9931,20)--(10.9931,19);
\draw (12.2598,20)--(12.2598,19);
\draw (13.52644,20)--(13.52644,19);
\draw (14.7930,20)--(14.793,19);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does a normal tabular suffice? `nicematrix` package has an option `hvlines` to automatically draw all the horizontal and vertical rules.

Comment: Here it is important to know what your table is for and why you would want to do it in TikZ, when LateX already has tables.

Comment: And of course, if you still want to use Ti*k*Z for that, you may want to use a `foreach` loop to create your cells instead of these weirdly precise coordinates.

Comment: Thank you @SebGlav. I am creating lesson notes using TikZ for my students. It's really a new way I am trying. I know the tabular environment, but I am trying to fit a table within the tikz environment. I just don't know how to use the \foreach command yet.

Comment: I posted an answer using `matrix of nodes` which is a better solution than a `foreach` loop, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this with Ti*k*Z (which I still don't understand, since you can mix a real table with Ti*k*Z drawings, but anyway), you can use `matrix of nodes`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzset{
    mymat/.style={
          matrix of nodes,
          anchor=center,
          nodes=draw,nodes in empty cells,
          minimum height=10mm,
          minimum width=15mm,
          align=center,
          column sep=-\pgflinewidth
          },
    }
    
\begin{document}
 
\lipsum[1]\\

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (14,3);
        \node[anchor=center,draw,fill=red!15] at (7,3) {Example 3};
        \node[anchor=center,text width=13cm,align=center] at (7,2)
            {\small The table above gives values of a function  $f$  at selected values of  $x$ . Which of the following conclusions is supported by the data in the table?};       
        \matrix[mymat] (m) at (7,0.8)
                {
                 & & & & & & & & \\
                };
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: table with matrix of nodes]

Answer (score 2):

Something similar with `tcolorbox` for the `example` environment and a "regular" `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{myexample}[1][]{
enhanced, sharp corners, coltitle=black, fontupper=\small,
colback=white, attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
boxed title style={sharp corners, colback=red!30},
title={Example~\thetcbcounter},
#1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{myexample}
\centering
The table above gives values of a function  $f$  at selected values of  $x$. Which of the following conclusions is supported by the data in the table?

\begin{tabular}{*{9}{|p{8mm}}|}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{7mm}&&&&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{myexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]